# How to run workflow in specific DateTime (eg. if BreachDateTime == NOW() ; run workflows)

Tags: workflow, datetime

I'm developing a service cloud org. I've already created the solution for getting the Breach DateTime for Turn Around Time per Case (respected the business hours). I thought that workflows is answer for breaching the TAT that I set to escalate the case to the next Level but its not working :(
[image]

Thanks in advance guys :)

Comment: If you're wanting a Workflow to fire off a DateTime field, which I assume you'd be doing via Time-Based Workflow... keep in mind that you're dealing with a SFDC limiation that it can only fires every 15 minutes.  See the attached URL for more details.  http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en_US

Comment: dan appleman's advanced apex 3rd edition chapter 7 has a pattern to do this - you use a custom `asyncRequest__c` object with a startdatetime field - read the chapter. a comment can't do justice to it